# Symfony2 : onKernelResponse called twice as MASTER_REQUEST

Tags: symfony, filter, listener

I'm using the event listener `onKernelResponse`.

I used :

```
if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST != $event->getRequestType()) {
    return;
}
```

It's having a `MASTER_REQUEST` twice in my action, there is one before the `<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head>`etc, and the other one as excepted after the end of the layout.

He is my `services.yml` :

```yaml
history.listener:
    class: VENDOR\MyBundle\Service\HistoryListener
    arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager, @logger, @history]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelController }
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.response, method: onKernelResponse }
```

Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally found the origin of the problem : the debug toolbar !

It actually sends an ajax request, meaning another `MASTER_REQUEST`..

My solution is to filter on Controller, with a white/black list of controller's names.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the code I'm using (so you can easily exclude some other controllers if needed).

```php
public function __construct()
{
    $this->classesExcluded = array("Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\Controller\ProfilerController");
}


public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
{
    $controller = $event->getController();

    if (!is_array($controller) || HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST != $event->getRequestType() || in_array(get_class($controller[0]), $this->classesExcluded)) {
        return;
    }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I ended up doing this - `strpos($event->getRequest()->attributes->get('_controller'), 'WebProfilerBundle') !== false`

Not sure how wise it is but does the trick.

Comment: Sometimes it is `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\RedirectController` so you might want to exclude it as well.

Comment: In my case I had Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController calling second time. I had to fix an error and then all worked fine.