# How do I access the logged in user in Symfony 3.3 in an Event Subscriber without losing the web profiler

Tags: symfony, events, listener, symfony-3.3

I am relatively new to Symfony 3, and indeed object oriented concepts, so apologies if I am asking something dumb.

I am building an application with multiple groups, where users can be members of more than one group, and may have different roles in each group.

Consequently I am loading roles dynamically - on each request, and comparing with the group they are accessing.  This is also to provide some protection against user privilege escalation by the logged in user switching groups by making a manual alteration to the browser address - if they change to the group there they have fewer (or no) privileges I am loading the roles before executing the controller.

Having research it seems that an event subscriber tied to the kernel.request or kernel.controller event is the right way to do this.

I need to access the user within this event subscriber, and have done this by injecting the TokenStorageInterface.

If I access $this->tokenStorage->getToken() I have a null, but if I access $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser() I get the valid current logged in user, but lose the developer web profiler - which is extremely useful to me.  It also indicates to me that I'm doing something which interferes with the operation of Symfony 'under the hood' - which may have consequences later.

So my question is; why am I losing the web profiling toolbar, and how can I get it back?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I eventually noticed that my event was being triggered twice - and further research suggested that the web profiler toolbar was firing the event itself.

I don't know why this meant that the token from tokenStorage was NULL but when I excluded the web profiler from firing using the accepted answer to the question below the behaviour reverted to what I would expect.  It may help others;

[Symfony2 : onKernelResponse called twice as MASTER_REQUEST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133802/symfony2-onkernelresponse-called-twice-as-master-request)